# Can't stat file after inotify IN_CREATE signal

Tags: python, inotify

Unfortunately my implementation is far too complex for me copy paste here (700+ lines), so I will explain as best as I can. I am using pyinotify to monitor a directory and check for, among other things, file creation. Every time a file is created, an `IN_CREATE` signal/flag is generated. I take this to mean that the file has been created. I then try to access the file's information via the following command

```
os.stat ( '/foo/bar.txt.swx' ).st_mode
```

but this generates the following error

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/foo/bar.txt.swx'
```

I believe one of three things is happening, can someone confirm which one:

1. I made a stupid mistake such as immediately deleting the file in the python script
2. inotify is non blocking, and the OS deleted the file before I could process the `IN_CREATE` signal (this happens a lot with complex saving methods such as vim's)
3. `IN_CREATE` does not mean what I think it means (see below).

[image]

Comment: so, have you tried breaking down your code a bit? (e.g. mock up some data and skip early processing steps to see where the saving issue is occurring), seems like that would help you figure out where the error is occurring. If it's a temp file, do you know where it gets deleted?

Comment: @JeffTratner I think inotify is non blocking. I don't have time to check for this right now, but I'm going to do a `sleep (100)` on a CREATE signal, then see if I can delete the file that was just created. My guess is that inotify does not lock the file.